# Using thymeleaf to show one of html forms

Tags: java, html, spring, rest, thymeleaf

I am new to spring and came up with this to show html page with my http request:

```
@ResponseBody
@GetMapping("/addStop")
public String showAddStopForm() throws IOException {
     String formHtml = Files.readString(Path.of("lab-1/src/main/resources/templates/stops.html")); //Path to your html file
     return formHtml;
}
```

It works well, but displays the whole html file. I would like to make it possible to show a certain form depending on http request, so I won't have to create 10+html files for a project
.

I tried using thymeleaf and so my code for outputing one of the forms looks like the following:

```
@GetMapping("/my-page")
    public String myPage(@NotNull Model model) throws  IOException{
        model.addAttribute("formType", "my-page");
        return "stops";
    }
```

But I get error page each time.

That's how my stops.html looks for now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <title>Add stop</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form th:if="${formType} == 'addStop'" method="POST" action="/stops">
    <label for="stop">Stop:</label>
    <input type="text" id="stop" name="stop"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  <form th:if="${formType} == 'my-page'" method="GET" action="/stops">
    <label for="stop">Stop:</label>
    <input type="text" id="qwe" name="stop"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Path to stops.html looks like following: src>main>resources>templates

```
pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.codebind</groupId>
    <artifactId>lab-1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>lab-1</name>
    <description>Working stuff</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>13.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```
StopsController:
package com.codebind.lab1;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/stops")
public class StopsController {

    @Autowired
    private final StopDao stopsDao;

    public StopsController(StopDao stopsDao) {
        this.stopsDao = stopsDao;
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @GetMapping()
    public ArrayList<Stops> getAllStops() throws SQLException {
        try {
            return stopsDao.getAllStops();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/{name}")
    public Stops getStopByName(@PathVariable("name") String stopName) throws SQLException {
        return stopsDao.getStopByName(stopName);
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @GetMapping("/addStop")
    public String showAddStopForm() throws IOException {
         String formHtml = Files.readString(Path.of("lab-1/src/main/resources/templates/stops.html"));
         return formHtml;
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @PostMapping("/addStop")
    public String addStop(@RequestParam("stop") String stopName) {
        try {
            stopsDao.insertStop(new Stops(stopName));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return "redirect:/stops";
    }

    @GetMapping("/my-page")
    public String myPage(@NotNull Model model) throws  IOException{
        model.addAttribute("formType", "my-page");
        return "stops";
    }
}
```

I would be glad to receive any help on that one.

I was trying to get some info on it, but every time i tried, it still showed the whole page.